# Call ServiceStack API Programmatically

Tags: servicestack

What are the best ways to call a servicestack API from asp.net website. Service is running in IIS.
All the methods inside the service stack require authentication first.

I tried with JsonServiceClient and HttpWebRequest. First time when I authenticate, service gives me cookies
ss-id and ss-pid and I store in cookies collection. Now when I request another method It says, You are not authorised.

The problem is, in the second request Cookies are not maintained. However if you test the service from browser it self. It do create cookies first during Authorization and in second request, It gives you proper response.

Below is my code. With JsonServiceClient and HttpWebRequest

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Login loginModel)
    {
        #region ServiceStack Call
        HttpCookie ck;
        string baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.101";
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
        var authResponse = client.Send<AuthenticateResponse>(new Authenticate
        {
            UserName = loginModel.UserName,
            Password = loginModel.Password,
            RememberMe = true
        }); 
        foreach (System.Net.Cookie cookie in client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(baseUrl)))
        {
            if (cookie.Name == "ss-id")
            {
                ck = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name);
                ck.Value = cookie.Value;
                ck.Expires.AddDays(1); //Check when to expire the cookie
                Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below Code with HttpWebRequest

```
protected string CallToApi(string baseUrl, bool createCookie)
    {
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        System.Uri uri = new Uri(baseUrl);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Timeout = 200000;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    if (createCookie)
                    {
                        //Create Cookies
                    }
                }

                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**How to give call to second method?**

`http://192.168.1.101/api/teamleaders`  URL

When calling this Url, Can I persist my cookies? or there must be out of the box in ServiceStack itself.

Comment: Are you using the default ServiceStack `CredentialsAuthProvider` as your auth provider?  Or a custom implementation?

Comment: I am using CustomCredentialsAuthProvider
Tried with CredentialsAuthProvider as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JsonServiceClient should persist cookies.  I've used the following code (with the default `CredentialsAuthProvider`) successfully:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUri);

var authResponse = client.Post(new Auth
{
    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    RememberMe = true
});
```

Note: this is with version 3.9.71, NOT the new v4 stack which I haven't yet had the opportunity to upgrade to.  The same 'should' work with a custom auth provider inheriting from `CredentialsAuthProvider`.

Comment: Correct. Does it persist cookies when we access other methods just after this call. However I am using version 4.0 but that should not be a problem.

Comment: So long as you use the same `JsonServiceClient` instance, all cookies should persist for subsequent requests to the API you've authenticated with.

Comment: Thanks Steve. 
How about HttpWebRequest?
With JsonServiceClient I can access API's all methods, with same Client.

Comment: @devbhagat you can use the instance `client.RequestFilter/ResponseFilter` delegates to get access to the underlying WebRequest API's, which can also be registered globally as `ServiceClientBase.GlobalRequestFilter/ResponseFilter` properties.

Comment: @devbhagat you can also get the raw HttpWebResponse with `client.Get<HttpWebResponse>(url)`, see the wiki on [.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#accessing-raw-service-responses) for more info.

Comment: @devbhagat Regarding your question about using HttpWebRequest, I'm not sure what you want to do?  Are you trying to figure out which client to use?  Using `JsonServiceClient` means you don't need to maintain any cookie related code...